# Is it ever beneficial to communicate qubits that aren't EPR pairs?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-networks

When Alice wants to send a qubit $q$ to Bob, she doesn't have to send $q$ itself. She can instead generate an EPR pair $(a, b)$, send $b$ to Bob, and [teleport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) $q$ to Bob by consuming $(a,b)$ and sending some classical fixup bits. This is hugely advantageous because, for example, it means that the process can be retried if the initial sending fails. In other words, $b$ can be transmitted using error *detecting* codes whereas transmitting $q$ would require much more expensive error *correcting* codes, and this makes it much cheaper to send $b$.

As far as I can tell, this is not an isolated incident. Anytime you have some sort of communication scenario, especially if there's the possibility of noise, it seems like it's better to send Bell pair halves rather than sending anything else. Even for protocols like entanglement distillation, where you'd expect to be sending really fancy error corrected states... instead you just send a bunch of raw Bell pairs and do the error correction across classical channels.

So my question is: what are communication scenarios where sending Bell pair halves *isn't* the right thing to do? Where it's demonstrably less efficient than something else, ignoring classical communication costs (because the internet is pretty darn cheap). Especially if the scenario involves surviving noise.

Comment: This could be the case if it's easier (in fidelity or other terms) to transmit qubits than to apply 2-qubit gates (as you'd need to for the teleportation).  E.g., in a photonic-based system it might be much simpler for Alice to send $q$ to Bob than to entangle it with $a$.